# Is there a way to check if google map API js file is tampered with

Tags: google-maps-api-3

For security reasons we are currently performing tamper checks for externally hosted js files that are included in our web solution. The Google Map API js (`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<api-key-goes-here>&libraries=places`) is one of them.

For all our externally hosted js libraries we perform a basic HMAC check to ensure these external files are checked against known values on a daily basis for any changes. Not necessarily a full tamper proof approach, but it allows us to track any changes to them.

What we find though is that the Google Map API js, using a HMAC approach, seems to change quite frequently. Possibly due to its dynamic contents.

Apart from doing a file compare to determine what data/code is dynamic in the js, is there be a better way to do this altogether? I.e. does Google provide HMACs for their existing libraries or does it provide other mechanisms to ensure their libraries are tamper resistant.

Comment: Request a specific version, update the hash when you update the version.  See: [versioning](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions)

Comment: @geocodezip thanks for the obvious but effective solution :)